# How to run multiple scripts each of which runs forever through one script?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Suppose I have the following two scripts:

```
#!/bin/sh
while true
do
    #Do something
    sleep 1m
done
```

and

```
#!/bin/sh
while true
do
    #Do something else
    sleep 1m
done
```

called `First.sh` and `Second.sh` respectively.

Now I want to create a script called `Start.sh` which would run both of them at the start of the computer:

```
#!/bin/sh
/path/to/files/First.sh
/path/to/files/Second.sh
```

The problem with the above is: `First.sh` runs forever and `Second.sh` never gets executed. `Second.sh` runs only after I kill `First.sh`. How to start them both simultaneously?

p.s.: In place of `First.sh` one could have put `chromium-browser` in `Start.sh`. `Second.sh` wouldn't start unless `chromium-browser` is killed.

Comment: why can't both be in one?

Comment: how would that be? Sorry, it may be too stupid.

Comment: put "notify-send 'New Screenshot' 'Taken'" before `sleep` in the first script?

Comment: Actually I would like to run 'chromium-browser' and 'another application'. Unless I don't kill chromium-browser, the other application doesn't start.

Comment: I think the examples are misleading. I will try to improve that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `&˙ at the end of each line and both scripts will run in background independently of each other:

```
#!/bin/sh
/path/to/files/First.sh &
/path/to/files/Second.sh &
```